# StringTemplate 4 <if> doesn't seem to work

Tags: if-statement, stringtemplate

I've only been using StringTemplate 4 for a week, so it's probably something I'm doing, but I don't seem to be able to make the `<if>` work.

I'm using 4.02 (since that's the latest in Maven repository).  I have a class called `Variable`.  This is a snippet:

```
class Variable
{
  ...
  public boolean isArray()
  {
    return _bIsArray;
  }
}
```

I have a template that has a line(delimiter is `$`, `$`):

```
$if(x.isArray)$ $ArrayAdd(x, className)$ $endif$
```

If I remove the `if` and simply let it execute `$ArrayAdd(...)$` for everything, the `ArrayAdd` is clearly executed.  I then put the `$if$` back in.  I also put a print statement in `isArray()` and `isArray()` is getting executed and returns `false` most of the time, but does return `true` once in a while (for exactly the cases I expected).  However, `$ArrayAdd` never gets executed from within the `$if$`.

I looked at the trace (which I'm not good at reading) and got:

```
declareSetGet:0227: load_local    0         stack=[ ], calls=ObjectClass _sub1  
declareSetGet, sp=-1, nw=0
declareSetGet:0230: load_prop     #25:"isArray" stack=[  
altLocation<CUSTOM>::Array<1>::Custom<altLocationObj> ], calls=ObjectClass _sub1 
declareSetGet, sp=0, nw=0
declareSetGet:0233: brf           254       stack=[ null ], calls=ObjectClass _sub1 
declareSetGet, sp=0, nw=0
ObjectClass:0121:   newline                 stack=[ ], calls=ObjectClass, sp=-1, nw=959
ObjectClass:0122:   write_str     #15:"}"   stack=[ ], calls=ObjectClass, sp=-1, nw=0
```

This is one of the cases where I would expect the `ArrayAdd` template to be executed.  Obviously, it doesn't.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: StringTemplate 4.0.7 is in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22ST4%22

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you should do this:

```
$if(x.array)$ $ArrayAdd(x, className)$ $endif$
```

Specifically, use `x.array` instead of `x.isArray` because the name of the property is "array" and the "is" is just a prefix per the Java Beans convention for boolean property accessors.

Comment: I would have bet that wouldn't make a difference.  I would have lost :) It works correctly now!  I still don't understand why it was calling the routine but apparently not using the result (where you're version does).  But, I'll move on.  Thanks for the help.